# Create own mail client using PHP,MYSQl

Tags: php, mysql, email

I want to create own mail client like outlook by using PHP and MYSQL..

I don't know where to start...?

can anyone help me...

thank u in advance...

Comment: Divide an conquer... first off start by breaking the problem into smaller pieces and start with the basic server stuff first like connecting to mail servers and things. Then come back and ask for specifics. This question is quite broad and I think you won't get too much help here...

Comment: ya u right asken....thank u for ur suggestion..first i planned to design the template,i designed,,waht is the second step..can u tell?

Answer (score 4):

Google maybe?

[Old (dead) URL](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Building-A-PHPBased-Mail-Client-part-1/)

New URL:
http://www.devshed.com/c/a/php/building-a-php-based-mail-client-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to plan this out extensively first

1. Write down all the things your mail client will do. Start SMALL
2. Create a user interface via HTML ( I recommend using bootstrap framework for ease of CSS ) for each view ( Send a message form looks like, inbox looks like )
3. Create your sending/receiving engine, I have no idea where to start i'm afraid. So like someone mentioned, get familiar with mail server stuff.

Make it as basic as possible to start out. Organize the rest as add-on's.